# how we can install java and mysql on one click installation?

Tags: java, mysql

how multiple software install on single click?

Comment: please add some more information. do you want all the software to be one installer-file or is a batch file that simply starts both installers enough? (the last isn't, i'm sure, but i hope this shows why you should provide more information)

Comment: What operating system are you installing this on?

Comment: If you need to install MySQL on so many machines that creating a custom installer is worth the effort, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A whole bunch of scripts, turned into a program.

Comment: The following will install the JAVA SDK in a batch file.  I assume something similar is available fore MySQL. search for "mysql silent install" http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/sdksilent.html
start /w jdk-1_5_0_14-windows-i586-p.exe /S /V"/qn ADDLOCAL=ToolsFeature INSTALLDIR=%INSTALLDIR%\Apps\Java\jdk1.5.0_14 REBOOT=ReallySuppress JAVAUPDATE=0"

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an application that takes care of downloading and installing your basic sofware for a computer check out:

http://ninite.com

The only problem is, it doesn't install MySQL, probably because usually installing MySQL server requires quite a bit of configuration to make sure it fits your needs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you are looking at a hosting service that has "one-click install" services.  In that case, go to your control panel, find the one-click application menu, and click the applications you want to install.

Please note that this is a terrible system.  These web applications from automatic service installers are rarely updated, and are hard to apply updates yourself after the fact (and you WILL need to update them).  It is much better to go through the trouble of learning the install yourself, so when upgrade time comes you stand at least a chance of getting it done.